# Maximo Anywhere Applications not lunching

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

Dears I have Maximo Anywhere 7.6.3.1 the applications not lunching i am getting the following error with android :
this issue suddenly appear for all Maximo Anywhere version 7.6.1 ,7.6.2

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from
>   'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
>   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears 
I got from IBM email Have the following link which you can change the dojo file so you can fix the issue permanently 
[Fix the issue](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10879639&myns=swgtiv&mynp=OCSSPJLC&mync=E&cm_sp=swgtiv-_-OCSSPJLC-_-E)

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue caused by a Chrome update, Updating to Chrome 73 on the device causes the issue. You can either uninstall Chrome updates or contact IBM Maximo Anywhere support for a fix.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10876700